# Why can you not factorialize all Real numbers??

Tags: real-numbers, factorial

I am a high school student and I learnt Factorials today. The Professor told that you can only factorialize natural numbers. Why is it so??

Is there a way to get the factorial of all Real numbers???

Comment: The gamma function generalizes factorials.

Comment: The gamma function is not defined on integers that are not positive

Comment: [This article](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2007-09.pdf) describes how Euler answered to your question in 1728.

Comment: The Davis reference there is a good read

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem

Answer (score 3):

To see why, consider this: Take $\pi$ things. In how many different ways can you order them? Does that make sense?

If you discard the combinatorial aspect, and focus on the algebraic aspect (namely $0!=1$ and $n!\cdot(n+1)=(n+1)!$), then there are many ways to generalize this to be valid for (almost) all real numbers, but the most common is the so-called $\Gamma$ function:
$$
\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt
$$
with $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$.

The $\Gamma$ function is undefined on $\{0,-1,-2,\ldots\}$. This is basically unavoidable if you want the defining algebraic property above to hold. On the other hand, we have $\Gamma(\pi+1)\approx 7.188$, giving something like an answer to the question in the first paragraph.

But note that the $\Gamma$ function *is not the factorial*. The factorial works on the natural numbers and only the natural numbers.

Comment: all real numbers *except integers that are not positive*

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Already fixed.